# Stored Procedures or writing queries on c# file

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing a .net C# based desktop based application....and m kind of stuck at deciding whether to write queries inside stored procedures or on my .cs file itself..this desktop application has a search/filter/report queries alot....and after development i have to move my applications' database to a server which is hosted on internet online....so which one's cost is lower to hit the server and is more efficient in transactions.....

I request you to please elobrate your ans..

PS:: I am newbie to development..so apologies if anything was incorrect :)

Comment: THat is SO opinion based that it is not even funny. With a lot of good and a tremendous amount of totally idiotic arguments used on both sides. Being a newbie I would suggest using Entity Framework for the start and taking it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, it depends highly on the situations you are in. When you put you queries in the code-files (c#), for each piece of code changing you have to recompile all your program and publish it again and again which is very time and energy consuming process, in which cases, make you encounter very difficult situations that even may lead to project failure.

As a newbie, I strongly recommend you separate your code files from business rules and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Its often a matter of preference. For simply queries (I.e. select id,name from contacts) I will usually write those inline (using dapper as an ORM) and am quite happy to work that way.

For more complicated queries, i.e. multi-table joins with lots of complicated sorting, filters etc, I would tend to put that code into a SP and call the SP to get the results (again using dapper).

There is not going to be much of a difference in building the sql in c# and calling the server with it versus executing a SP to do the same thing, with a possible slight edge to the SP method in some cases.

Often it comes down to your skills and access to the production systems. In bigger shops it is rare that a front-end dev has the ability to modify stored procedures in production without going thru a rigorous deployment process and going thru a DBA gatekeeper - this will tend to (for better or worse) often cause those devs to move more code into the front-end versus the database.

On the other hand, if you have complete unrestricted access to the front-end and backend, sometimes its nice to be able to tweak stored procedure in production, without needing to redeploy your code

The really is not a right way (or a wrong way) - it will depend on a lot of things.

Comment: much appreciated answer sir...